# query contacts based on opportunity field

Tags: soql, query

I'm trying to query contacts linked to an opportunity that share the same account. I currently have this query, and it returns data.  however, the data is incorrect.

```
Select Name, email, Account.Name, Account.Description
From Contact WHERE Account IN (Select AccountName From Opportunity where Division__c='Sterling')
```

Comment: What do you man by "the data is incorrect"? Can you please **[edit]** your post to be more clear?

Comment: Do you have any separate contact look up field on Opportunity? or you are using OpportunityContactRole to link between contact & opportunity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be using the AccountId field in the where clause as there's no `Account` field on the Contact object. You would then also want to select AccountId in the query from Opportunities. Something like this:

```
Select Name, email, Account.Name, Account.Description
From Contact WHERE AccountId IN (Select AccountId From Opportunity where Division__c='Sterling')
```